# How to enable two wbesite to work on Nginx Digital ocean server

Tags: php, nginx, digital-ocean

So while following this tutorial to implement two website on my NginX server.

[**Lin to the Website**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-websites-securely-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I created two folder as follow

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/ideconnect.com
```

my file look like this

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/ideconnect.com/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name ide-portal.com www.ide-portal.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Then the other website

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/iclock.com

server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/iclock.com/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name iclock.in www.iclock.in;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Also I have created the SYMLINKS properly

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/ideconnect.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ideconnect.com



sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/iclock.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/iclock.com
```

After this when I got to my ip address I can only see the default Nginx Page also now the info.php configuration page is also not visible.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can check to begin with:

- Did you restart nginx?
- Are you sure your nginx configuration is set up to include `.com` files? I think the default is to include all `.conf` files. You can check that in your nginx configuration file and then adapt that or modify the extension of your symlinks.

Comment: I am getting my html page now , and Yes .com is allowed as file name.  But when I uploaded mY Laravel website I am getting following error `Mcrypt PHP extension required` . www.ideportal.com/public

Comment: @Vikram So what was the problem, you needed to restart nginx? By the way, installing php extensions should be easy but depends on your operating system.

Comment: it was my browsers problem , I just did ctrl+f5 and then it started whoing the page . I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on Digital Ocean provider

Comment: @Vikram I don't use Ubuntu, but if I remember correctly it would be something like `# apt-get search php` to search for php related packages and then you can install them with `# apt-get install ...`. You probably need the `mcrypt` and `php5-mcrypt` packages.

Comment: thanks Yes I found the ini file it was pretty easy . I will try to install these packages .I have been a Godaddy VPS user so every thing was out of the box , Recently switched to DO and Installed LEMP stack , so bit complicated for me :D

Comment: @Vikram Good luck :-)